# Xamarin android facebook auth NullReferenceException

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

I am faced with problem when trying to authenticate my app via facebook. After entering a username and password in the facebook form, I caught a `NullReferenceException`. 
I've noticed that it happens only when I compile with Android 6.0.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FirstPage), typeof(FirstPageRenderer))]
namespace Dating.Droid.Renderers
{
public class FirstPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public FirstPageRenderer()
        {
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;
            if (activity != null)
            {
                var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                    clientId: "MyFacebookId", // your OAuth2 client id
                    scope: "", // the scopes for the particular API you're accessing, delimited by "+" symbols
                    authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                    redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));

                auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        // Authenticated
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // The user cancelled
                    }
                };

                activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Exception appears on auth.Completed event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHYO4.png)

Stack Trace:   at Dating.Droid.Renderers.FirstPageRenderer+<>c.<.ctor>b__0_0 (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Auth.AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs eventArgs) [0x00002] in D:\Dev\Real\Xamarin\Dating\Dating.Droid\Renderers\FirstPageRenderer.cs:31

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: What is null? The `auth` variable? Add the stack trace to your anser

Comment: I've added a picture with exception information.